# Socket emit to room works for all sockets except the sender

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm creating a voting feature using socket.io. Sockets are placed into rooms by a `channelId`. Whenever any socket in the room emits a `vote` event, i'm trying to emit the current `vote-list` to all sockets in that room.

My problem is that if I have Sockets A, B, C in the same room, votes from Socket A are visible to B and C (that is, B and C's `on.('vote')` listeners are called), but NOT to A itself.

What i expect to happen, is that if Sockets A, B, C are in the same room, and A emits a `vote`, All sockets A, B, C `vote` listeners will be called.

**Client:**

These listeners are defined within methods, but i've singled them out for clarity. All variables are defined.

```
const socket = io('https://localhost:3001')

socket.emit('join-channel',{ 
    channelId: payload.channelId,
    senderId: socket.id
 })

socket.emit('vote',{
    senderId: socket.id,
    channelId: state.channelId,
    vote: payload.vote,
    userId: state.userId
})

socket.on(`vote`, function (data) {
    store.commit(MUTATIONS.SET_VOTES, data)
});
```

**Server**

module.exports = (app,server) => {
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('join-channel',data=>{
        socket.join(data.channelId)
    })

    socket.on('vote',data=>{
        postVote(data)
        let { channelId } = data

        socket.to(channelId).emit(`vote`,STORE[channelId])
        //socket.emit(`vote`,STORE[channelId]) //My workaround so that the socket's messages are emitted back to itself
    })


});
```

};

My current workaround is to add `socket.emit('vote',STORE[channelId])`, so that it can emit data back to itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design in the socket.io API.  This form you were using:

```
socket.to(channelId).emit(...)
```

is specifically designed to send to all sockets in the channelId room EXCEPT `socket`.

If you want to send to ALL users in that room, then change the above code to:

```
io.to(channelId).emit(...)
```

---

Here's a quote from the [socket.io doc for `socket.to()`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#sockettoroom):

> Sets a modifier for a subsequent event emission that the event will
>   only be broadcasted to clients that have joined the given room (the
>   socket itself being excluded).

Answer (score -1):

Let make a list of sockets and hide visibility to sender

```
var sockets = [A,B,C]
    socket.on('vote',data=>{
    let []tovisible = sockets - data.senderId 
    //emit event only tovisible arry
    socket.to(tovisible).emit(`vote`,STORE[channelId])
   }
```